# How to effectively wrap the source file in a function that will be exported to spec file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I want to ask a question to students, define the ranking of the operators (`+`, `/`, `-`, `*`, `^`).

The method I'm using requires that I use exports.function_name = function()
in order for the spec file to be able to import it.

However, I want students to not have to use the exports.function as this is not what they would do in the editor.

Therefore, I need to find an efficient way to wrap the code the student types in. This is what I have so far (src file: `../src/C3Q2.js`):

```
exports.StudentSolution = function()
{    
var operators = {
        "^": 4,
        "*": 3,
        "/": 2,
        "+": 1,
        "-": 0,
 };

return operators;//This works but I dont want the student to do this 
//extra step, the only thing they should have to do is define the variable
//operators                    
};
```

The file I am testing the src file is as follows (spec file):

```
var calculator = require("../src/C3Q2.js");

describe("precedence", function ()
{
it("check precedence", function () 
  {
   var solution =  calculator.StudentSolution();


  var product = solution["^"];

   expect(product).toBe(4);
  });
 });
```

This works but I want the student to just have to define operators variable. Is there a more efficient way to automate and wrap the function?

Comment: May I suggest you use UpperCamelCase _only_ for classes (combined with the `new` keyword)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but you can export the Object directly like this;

```
exports.StudentSolution = {
  "^": 4,
  "*": 3,
  "/": 2,
  "+": 1,
  "-": 0,
};
```

So that your test can reference it like so;

```
var calculator = require("../src/C3Q2.js");

describe("precedence", function() {
  it("check precedence", function() {
    var product = calculator.StudentSolution["^"];
    expect(product).toBe(4);
  });
});
```

This removes the "extra step" of the function, is that what you meant?